# What is the best way to sort normalized data?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, normalizr

For example I have this data from server

```
[{id: 1, pinned: true, date: 14.03.2019 ... }, 
 {id: 8, pinned: true, date: 20.02.2019 ...},
 {id: 2, pinned: false, date: 26.03.2019 ...},
 {id: 21, pinned: false, date: 25.03.2019 ...}, ...];
```

This data already sorted by date, but pinned items always on top.

After normalizing data with normalizr.js I will have my entities object and ids array like:

```
entities: { 1:[{id: 1, pinned: true, ... }, 8: { id: 2, pinned: true, ...}, ...},
ids: [1, 8, 2, 21 ...];
```

And I will store it in different reducers.

to render this data I use:

```
const List = (props) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {props.ids.map(id =>
        <Item id={id} key={id} />
      )}
    </ul>
  )
}
connect((state) => { ids: state.ids })(Item);

const Item = (props) => (
  <li>{props.contact.id}</li>
);

connect((state, ownProps) => { contact: state.entities[ownProps.id] })(Item)
```

But what if from server I will get the item like

```
{id: 30, pinned: false, date: 27.03.2019 ...}
```

This item should be been first in the list, but after pinned items.

How to sort the ids reducer ?

The one that comes into my head its to denormalize data sort it and normalize again. But this feels "wrong".

Maybe there is a way without denormalizing? Or another best way for this situation.

Thanks for helping guys!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the order is retained in results property, not in entities.

Take a look: https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/issues/9